# Limit the number of images saved in documents folder

Tags: iphone

I want to take 3 images and save it in the documents folder as IMAGE_1, IMAGE_2, and IMAGE_3. I want to limit the number of images to be just three images, which means the 4th image will be saved as the new "IMAGE_1" replacing the first image(old IMAGE_1), the 5th becomes "IMAGE_2", and so on. The codes below will save the images as IMAGE_1, IMAGE_2, IMAGE_3, IMAGE_4, ... how should I limit the number of images saved?

```
- (void) saveImage:(UIImage*)image 
{
    NSData *imageData =
    [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9f)];
    [imageData writeToFile:[self savePath] atomically:YES];
}

- (NSString*) savePath
{
    int i=1;
    NSString *path;
    do {
    path = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/Documents/IMAGE_%d.jpg", NSHomeDirectory(), i++];
} while ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]); 

    return path;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static int i=1;  // Place it below your @implementation yourclassname

- (void) saveImage:(UIImage*)image {
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.9f)];
    NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSString *path = [self savePath];

    if([fileMgr fileExistsAtPath:path])
        [fileMgr removeItemAtPath:path error:NULL];
    [imageData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
- (NSString*) savePath {
    if(i==4)
        i=1;
    return [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@/Documents/IMAGE_%d.jpg", NSHomeDirectory(), i++];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried your answer but all new images are saved as IMAGE_3 :(

Comment: Now Try above modified code, I modified it a bit, it was a minor mistake on my part.